# Can't launch unity bar with wacom tablet

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos CTH680 & I can't seem to be able to launch the unity bar with the pen. When I move the pen to the edge of the detection area, the unity bar doesn't reveal itself. The only way I can use the unity launcher with the pen is if I disable autohide, but then the unity launcher obstructs stuff on the left side of my screen. How do I get the pen to be able to reveal the unity launcher?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04—all of the wacom help out there seems to be for much older versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem. The solution was to just hold the Super key (or "windows") for a moment to make the launcher appear.

I think that any tablet can't do this, because the mouse can 'force' their position, while the pen have their limited area to move in the tablet. Though in my Bamboo Fun Pen & Touch, with the touch I can do this.

Comment: but I use the super key to type accents (à ê,etc.)